# I have a working grep command that works on the command line, but doesn't inside my perl script

Tags: perl, grep

I think it is probably due to escape characters.
Also the script and the file that is being accessed (input.scs), are in the same directory.

```
my @var=`grep -o '"[^"]\+"' ./input.scs | sed 's/"//g'`;
print "-D @var\n";
```

The output is returning empty when it actually should generate multiple lines.
The grep command searches for data within quotes and prints the data.

Comment: Backticks act as double-quoted strings. You need to escape `\ `

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @ikegami, you need to espace the backslash within the backtick operator, else Perl will try to interpolate it :

```
my @var = `grep -o '"[^"]\\+"' input.scs | sed 's/"//g'`;
```

However, instead of using external commands you could do that with a Perl on-liner like :

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while (m/"([^"]+)"/g)' input.scs
```

This will return the same output, ie the list of all matches, with double quotes removed.

Or if you want to edit the file in-place :

```
perl -pe 's/"([^"]+)"/$1/g' input.scs
```